# How To Connect to two different web server in localhost

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to built my website using react.

I am using webpack-dev-server for serving the react website at localhost:8080.

I have another server running in localhost:9000 which has the api's for our website.

But when I try to make a fetch request to the localhost:9000 to fetch data I am encountering the following error.

There has been a problem with your fetch operation: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': The origin of 'http://127.0.0.1:9000' should be same as 'http://localhost:8080'

How can I solve the it?

Comment: CORS headers perhaps? What language / framework is your API made in?

Comment: its made in python using Flask.

Comment: To just get it to work, you could try this: https://gist.github.com/blixt/54d0a8bf9f64ce2ec6b8 - but you might want to restrict the allowed origins when you run on production

Comment: Thanks. It worked.

Comment: Cool I'll write it up as an answer if that's cool?

Comment: yes. you should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the browser is preventing the request to the API because the host is different - this is controlled by [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) which the API can send to say "these are the hosts which are allowed to make requests". You can turn off this checking by using a wildcard - as described in this [gist here](https://gist.github.com/blixt/54d0a8bf9f64ce2ec6b8)

```py
def add_cors_headers(response):
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'DELETE, GET, POST, PUT'
        headers = request.headers.get('Access-Control-Request-Headers')
        if headers:
             response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = headers
    return response
app.after_request(add_cors_headers)
```

Comment: https://blog.skyred.fi/articles/better-crossdomain-snippet-for-flask.html This is a pretty solid example, here.